# Adding Products in bulk - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, products

How can I add products in bulk in magento 2?

Comment: What is a "bulk product"? This term does not exist in Magento, please describe what you want to achieve. Or do you mean "bulk add" products? There is an import feature but we'll need more information on what you need to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add bulk products using Import feature in Magento. Please find the below tutorials.
http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/import-products-data-in-magento-2/

For more advanced import, try this

https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexport

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html